# How delete Gmail account from Evolution?

Tags: unity, 13.04, empathy, evolution, gmail

I would use evolution only to work (company email/calendar/contacts etc), but it's already set up an gmail account. Unfortunately I can't delete it because the "delete" button is disabled for this account.

Private emails i want to have in Thunderbird. How can I remove it from the Evolution?  And still use google calendar and gtalk in empathy?

BR
Parasit

Comment: I had this problem. Open the menu, find "Onlie Accounts" and remove the Google account. The Evolution account just vanishes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is going to help; however, I had the same problem and eventually managed to get rid of the Gmail account via some combination of the following:

- Removing ~/.config/goa-1.0 and its contents.
- Removing my Jabber account from the online accounts (it was configured to use gmail.com).
- Removing a bunch of files named ~/config/evolution/sources/1377432950.21327.?@*myusername*.source, because they each contained a gmail.com setting.
- Removing Google from the online accounts.
- Adding Google back in the online accounts.

All of the above with Evolution shut down, of course. I'm not sure which of the above actions helped, but eventually Evolution didn't display the Gmail account anymore.

Comment: Great, i just remove file:
~/.config/goa-1.0/accounts.conf
and gmail account dissapear from evolution !!!

Comment: [how to shut down evolution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=802754)

Comment: on Ubuntu I just had to remove the account from the Ubuntu online accounts while Evolution was closed

Answer (score 1):

I bet you are seeing an email account from Online Accounts (i.e. a Microsoft account) that uses a Gmail address. To hide it, disable that account in Online Accounts, and the Gmail account should disappear from Evolution.

Answer (score 0):

In online accounts switch the use for your GMail account mail to off and leave calendar and chat on. This should remove the GMail account from Evolution and leave it in empathy.